# Concavity of composition

Tags: convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

I have a question about the concavity of a composition of functions. Suppose $f$ is a pdf (if needed, a normal pdf). Suppose $g$ is a concave function. 
Is $g(f(x))$ concave? Thanks in advance!

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: What are conditions?

Comment: you need the outer function to be strictly decreasing

Comment: So the function $g$ has to be decreasing? Why? No conditions for the inner function? Thanks a lot

Comment: You need both functions to be concave and also for the outer function to be strictly decreasing. You can see this by taking the second derivative of the composition and checking when it will be negative.

Comment: Thanks! I see :) So it will not work for the case with pdfs as inner functions?

Comment: it's fine to use a concave function as your inner function. In this case, the normal pdf is concave so you can use it. You have more restrictions on the outer function.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always true that the composition of concave functions is concave. For example, let $g(x) = -x^2$ with $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$. Then $g$ is concave but $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is not. We can easily see this by taking derivatives,

$$h'(x) = g'(f(x))f'(x) = 4xe^{-2x^2},\\
h''(x) = e^{-2x^2}(4-16x^2)$$

Since $h''(x)$ is not always negative (for example at $x=0$), we do not have concavity.

In general, $h''(x) = f''(x)g'(f(x))+f'(x)^2g''(f(x))$ will only be negative if $g$ is concave and also $g'(x) >0$ for all $x$.

Comment: If $f$ is concave, then we need $g^{\prime}$ to be positif instead?

Comment: Yes - this means we need $g$ to be an increasing function.

Comment: Yes. In your post, you wrote $g'(x) < 0$